# Adding list to already existing list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to copy the existing lists and then concatenates them together. I used the copy function which returns a pointer to the new lists. I'm having difficulty pointing last pointer of the first list to the first node in the other list.

```
Node *concatenates(Node *list1, Node *list2) {
    Node *n5;
    Node *n2;
    n5=copy(list1);
    n2=copy(list2);
    while(n5!=NULL)
      n5=n5->next;
    n5->next=n2; /* having trouble with this part */
    return n5;
 }
```

Comment: add your code for `copy()` and your `Node` struct, and specify what you mean by "having trouble"

Comment: It doesn't concatenates the list and gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: don't make a comment, edit all of those things into your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues here. I'll address your segfault:

```
while(n5!=NULL)
  n5=n5->next;
n5->next=n2
```

After the while loop, `n5` is guaranteed to be `NULL`, so `n5->next` is undefined and will produce a seg fault. This while loop will prevent the seg fault (but still won't work):

```
while(n5->next!=NULL)
  n5=n5->next;
n5->next=n2
```

Your other glaring issue is that you are taking the head of `list1`, putting it in `n5`, then throwing out the entire list with a while loop until `n5` is the tail of the list. You need to fix that, or you won't be returning what you expect.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by throwing the entire list. Do you mean that n5 gets set to the last node in the list? Should I declare another node and set it to point to n5 and loop through there to get to the end so m5 remains the same? My intention was to loop till the end of list 1 and then set the last element to point to the beginning of the other list.

Comment: I mean that you start by making `n5` the head of your list, then you throw out elements in that while loop until `n5` becomes the tail. There's nothing left pointing to the head of the list, so those nodes are lost forever.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Got it to work now it giving me segmentation errors. At least it adding to the list now. I declared a new node and set it to n5; Then did the loop and set the last element  to the new list. And return the pointer to head of n5.